# How to add the values which is present inside the array (or) Json?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I been wondering if someone fixed my issue. my code looks like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 //Adding New Check# and Check amount Text Boxes
         $scope.checks = [{checkNum1: '',checkAmt1:''}];


             $scope.add = function() {
               var newCheckNo = $scope.checks.length+1;
               $scope.checks.push({['checkAmt'+newCheckNo]:''});
             };
             
             $scope.tot = function() {
               return  $scope.checks;
             };
             
             $scope.total = function() {
               var value = "";
                 for(var i =0 ; i<=$scope.checks.length;i++ ){
                    value += $scope.checks.get('checkAmt1');
                  }
                return value;
             };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">
         <div ng-repeat="check in checks">
               <div class="form-group">
              <label>check Amount:</label>
               <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{'id'+($index+1)}}" ng-model="check['checkAmt'+($index+1)]" maxlength="6" />
               </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <button type="button"
              ng-click="add()">Add More</button>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <!--<p ng-repeat="check in checks">{{check['checkAmt'+($index+1)]}}</p>-->
</div>
  <label>{{tot()}}</label>
  <label>{{total()}}</label>
</div>
```

I am initializing `$scope.checks = [{checkAmt1:''}];` 
and pushing the additional values on clicking Add Button (`checkAmt2`,`checkAmt3`,...so on). i want to add those values(`checkAmt1+checkAmt2+`...so on) dynamically by using `{{total()}}`. `total()` function is calling, i know logic inside the for loop is wrong. Please help me to fix the logic (or) Suggest me if any other way to add those values.

Thanks in advance.

Note: please refer the result in full page view.

Comment: Why are you pushing  `{checkAmtX:''}` to the array? Why not just 1,2,3,..? I think it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: why not just 1,2,3..? i am not understand the meaning of this?. I am pushing dynamic checkAmtx to checks where x = 1,2,3...

Comment: the $scope.checks not only contains checkAmt, it also contains checkNum, (ie)$scope.checks = [{checkNum1: '',checkAmt1:''}];  i also edited my code.Sorry for no mentioning it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, it is not a proper way of using an array.
You can sum up column with same name and not dynamic name.

I think to make the entries distinct you have used in such manner. But it is not the good way and will make your operation on array complicated.

You can try to construct array in following way,

```
 $scope.checks = [{id:'',checkNum: '',checkAmt:''}];
```

The complete changed code will look like

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 //Adding New Check# and Check amount Text Boxes
         $scope.checks = [{id:'', checkAmt:''}];


             $scope.add = function() {
               var newCheckNo = $scope.checks.length+1;
               $scope.checks.push({'id':newCheckNo ,'checkAmt':''});
             };
             
             $scope.tot = function() {
               return  $scope.checks;
             };
             
             $scope.total = function() {
               var value = 0;
                 for(var i =0 ; i<$scope.checks.length;i++ ){
                    value += parseInt( $scope.checks[i].checkAmt);

                  }
                return value;
             };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">
         <div ng-repeat="check in checks">
               <div class="form-group">
              <label>check Amount:</label>
               <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{'id'+($index+1)}}" ng-model="check['checkAmt']" maxlength="6" />
               </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <button type="button"
              ng-click="add()">Add More</button>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <!--<p ng-repeat="check in checks">{{check['checkAmt']}}</p>-->
</div>
  <label>{{tot()}}</label>
  <label>{{total()}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..i wont repeat this kind of mistakes in future. your modified code working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why indeed you push into the array such objects, and not just numbers, but as you iterate over it - you can just access each value by index, then take the correct object's value:

```
for(var i =0 ; i<=$scope.checks.length;i++ ){
   value += $scope.checks[i]['checkAmt' + i];
}
```

Comment: the $scope.checks not only contains checkAmt, it also contains checkNum, (ie)$scope.checks = [{checkNum1: '',checkAmt1:''}]; i also edited my code. sorry for not mentioning it in the first place.